# XAML content is not updated properly in a .net MAUI app

Tags: ios, xaml, maui

In my .Net MAUI app, I have page 1 and page 2. On page 1, there is a StackLayout which is hidden or displayed based on viewmodel's data. Here is a simplified xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
   <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                      IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

   <ScrollView>
       <StackLayout Margin="30">
           <Label 
               Text="{Binding ComingAppointmentInfo}"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

           <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ComingAppointment, Converter={StaticResource ComingAppointmentToVisibilityConverter}}">
               <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 3*" RowDefinitions="*, *" Margin="50, 20">
                   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Date:" FontAttributes="Bold" />

                   <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding ComingAppointmentDate}"
                       Margin="0,0 "/>

                   <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Time:" FontAttributes="Bold"  />

                   <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding ComingAppointmentTime}"
                       Margin="0,0 "/>
               </Grid>

               <Label Text="{Binding AppointmentCountdownText}" />

               <Button 
                   Command="{Binding MakeVideoCallCommand}" 
                   Text="{Binding ButtonPhoneText}" 
                   IsEnabled="{Binding JoinCallEnabled}"
                   Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                   Margin="0, 20"/>

               <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   BorderColor="Transparent"
                   HasShadow="False">      
                   <Label Text="{Binding CancelAppointmentText}"
                       FontFamily="FontAwesome"
                       TextColor="Blue"
                       TextDecorations="Underline"
                       HeightRequest="75">
                       <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                           <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CancelAppointmentCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                   </Label>
               </Frame>

               <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="DarkGray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,30,0,30" />
               
           </StackLayout>

           <Label 
               Text="Schedule a new video call"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="0,20"/>
           
           <Button 
               Command="{Binding ScheduleAppointmentCommand}" 
               Text="{Binding ButtonScheduleAppointmentText}" 
               Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
       </StackLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

Initially, that StackLayout is invisible, so only a label and a button under it are displayed.

The user navigates to page 2 using the following call from the viewmodel:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AppointmentSchedulePage), true, scheduleParameter);
```

On page 2, the user takes some action after which he returns to page 1 by calling the following from the page 2 viewmodel:

```
            await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () => 
            { 
                await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync(); 
            });
```

Due to the changes made on page 2, now the StackLayout on page 1 becomes visible.

**But for some reason, the page still has only enough room for the initially visible two elements. So most of the content is pushed down and not displayed, unless you scroll to it. Moreover, the button and clickable label are now not responsive.**

This problem exists only in iOS (on my iPhone) and not on Android.

If I close my app and re-open it, the content is displayed properly, everything is visible, fits the screen, and is responsive.

I tried to replace PopAsync() with GoToAsync(), but it did not help. I also tried to set VerticalOptions of the parent StackLayout to FillAndExpand or StartAndExpand, but that did not help either. I also tried ForceLayout() on the page 1, but no luck.

Comment: For debugging, i think you could make ```StackLayout``` more simple to see if it is the issue with the layout.

Comment: Works well on my end. How do you change the proeprty in page1's viewModel? Do. you use a Messaging?

Comment: I would start by setting HeightRequest to EVERYTHING. (Except the outermost ScrollView)

Comment: @Liqun Shen-MSFT I don't use messaging. Property ComingAppointment is set in page 1's OnAppearing() based on the data changed in page 2's viewmodel. So page 1 does not communicate to page 2 to set the property, rather, both pages independently access the data. So  if ComingAppointment is not null, the converter returns true, and more stuff becomes visible.

Comment: @H.A.H. If I make HeightRequest = 600 on the StackLayout right under the ScrollView, the screen looks normal, but in horizontal position scrolling does not work, so the content does not fit the screen, and there is no way to scroll. You suggested to set HeightRequest to everything, but I am not sure how that may work. All devices have different sizes, so I am not sure what values I should provide for other elements inside of the ScrollView.

Comment: @DavidShochet do not make it 600, Set the inner, lets say 30, 30, 60. Then we go outer as the sum of the inner 30+30+60 = 120. Then we do the outers 120 + 60 + 60, set the outermost to 240. And so on.

Comment: Did it work on the iphone simulator in debug mode?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I cannot run the app on any simulator

Comment: @H.A.H. I added Height Request on every control, but scrolling still doesn't work. Besides, it seems to me that hard-coding height of every control is not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidShochet It is not that bad. Also the most important thing here is to see if it works. A little bit diagnostic to see where the problem comes from.

Comment: @H.A.H. So it does not work anyway :(

Comment: @DavidShochet I need a way to simulate this.

Comment: @H.A.H. The issue is fixed by setting the scroll view's vertical options to FillAndExpand. No need to set HeightRequest. Thank you for your effort to help.

Comment: @DavidShochet Isn't this Scroll View your outermost element? The one element in the content page? Also, what effect do you think "AndExpand" has? I have doubts...

Comment: @H.A.H. No, there is StackLayout around it. I don't know why it does not show up, I can see it in Edit mode. I cannot answer your question about AndExpand. I found this suggestion elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidShochet Well, you were missing one space on first and last line. Made this small edit, if you do not mind. Anyway, this is another story. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: @H.A.H. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed by setting the scroll view's vertical options to FillAndExpand.